# vue create でVue packages version mismatchのエラーがでる

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

vue create を入れると下記エラーがでます。

```
mac:vue-nuxt hogehoge$ vue create my-app
/Users/hogehoge/.nodebrew/node/v12.13.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/index.js:10
  throw new Error(
  ^

Error: 

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.5.17 (/Users/hogehoge/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.10 (/Users/hogehoge/.nodebrew/node/v12.13.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/package.json)

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hogehoge/.nodebrew/node/v12.13.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/index.js:10:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hogehoge/.nodebrew/node/v12.13.1/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/vue-jscodeshift-adapter/src/parse-sfc.js:1:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
```

vue-template-compilerのアップデートnodeのバージョンアップなど色々行ったのですが毎回ここのエラーが変わりません。

なにか解決方はないでしょうか？

Comment: 解決した場合、ぜひ回答を承認・投票してください。回答を承認するにはその回答の横にあるチェックマークをクリックします。 [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

vueとvue-template-compilerのバージョンが合わない（ミスマッチ）というエラーが出ていますね。2つのパッケージのバージョンを合わせれば解決するかもしれません。

再現はしていないのでわかりませんが、他のページで似たような質問が投稿されていたので共有します。

推測ですが、こちらのURLの内容と同じ状況かもしれません。 
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4394

パッケージの場所がそれぞれ異なる。（`/Users/hogehoge/node_modules/...`　と、`/Users/hogehoge/.nodebrew/node/v12.13.1/lib/node_modules/...`）ので、もし　`/Users/hogehoge/node_modules/`がアクシデントで作られたものであれば削除すると解決する可能性があります。（実際に使っていないか注意して削除してくださいね）

（hinaloeさんと同じ回答です）

### そのほかに見つかった情報

こちらがほぼ同じ質問のようです（英語）：
https://superuser.com/questions/1456372/how-do-i-remove-the-error-in-vue-create

似たような質問と回答：
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397688/how-do-i-fix-a-vue-packages-version-mismatch-error-on-laravel-spark-v4-0-9

Comment: 上2つのリンクはまさに同じ状況に見えますね！

Comment: /Users/hogehoge/node_modules/
をアンインストールしたらうまくいきました

Answer (score 0):

プロジェクト外で`npm install`等をしているように見えます。

もし、`/Users/hogehoge/` がプロジェクトディレクトリ**ではなく**、そこで-gなどを付けないnpm isntallを行ったなどの過去がありその直下に`node_modules`ディレクトリが**あるのであれば**それを**削除**または**名前の変更**をしてみてください。